# Resize toolbar SWT

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I am trying to set the height of ToolBar to match other items in the grid layout. Here is the code I am using:

```
public TestSwt() {
    Display display = new Display();
    shell = new Shell(display, SWT.SHELL_TRIM);
    shell.setSize(800, 800);

    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
    gridLayout.numColumns = 1;
    shell.setLayout(gridLayout);

    Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    composite.setSize(100, 100);
    GridLayout childGridlayout = new GridLayout();
    childGridlayout.numColumns = 10;
    composite.setLayout(childGridlayout);
    composite.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));

    final Link link = new Link(composite, SWT.NULL);
    link.setText("Link1");
    Link link1 = new Link(composite, SWT.NULL);
    link1.setText("Link2");


    ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.VERTICAL);
    ToolItem item = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.PUSH);
    item.setText("toolbar");
    // Trying to resize toolbar
    Point size = toolBar.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, link.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT).y);
    toolBar.setSize(size);
    toolBar.pack();



    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }

    display.dispose();
}
```

The output I get is:

[image]

The output I want is:

[image]

I am sure I am missing something very basic. Any help will be really appreciated.

Edit:

As Andrew suggested I set the GridData as LayoutData. It did resize the toolBar but the text is not visible.
Using the code:

```
GridData toolBarlayout = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.TOP, true, true);
toolBarlayout.heightHint = link.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT).y;
ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.VERTICAL);
toolBar.setLayoutData(toolBarlayout);

ToolItem item = new ToolItem(toolBar, SWT.PUSH|SWT.TOP);

item.setText("toolbar");
```

The output is something like:

[image]

Comment: For a start you have a `GridLayout` set on `composite` - the layout will override any sizes you set on children of the composite.

Comment: @greg-449: What you suggest.

Comment: Toolbars really don't like being smaller than they want to be. Why not just use another Link?

Comment: I need a popup when you click on the toolbar.'

Answer (score 0):

The GridLayout will allow the link widgets to grow to the height of the row, and will size the height of the row to accommodate the toolbar, and the toolbar wants to be at least as big as it is in your output. For that reason, you might have to explicitly set the height you want for the ToolBar (in pixels) rather than taking it from the Link. But you can put some logging in to see what `computeSize()` is actually returning.

I would create a GridData for the ToolBar, set the heightHint on the GridData to the height you want, and call toolBar.setLayoutData.

```
GridData toolBarLayoutData = new GridData();
toolBarLayoutData.heightHint = ...;
toolBar.setLayoutData(toolBaryLayoutData);
```

Comment: It did resize the toolbar but the text is not visible now. Edited the question to reflect the same.